# How to enable JS colouring in non-js projects?

Tags: javascript, c++, eclipse

I have the `Eclipse Web Developer Tools` plugin installed. In new project menu there is a JavaScript project, and files in that project have proper syntax  highlighting.

I setting up to work on a project, that is mostly C++, a part is written in JavaScript. I have imported the project as "C/C++ project with external Makefile". Unfortunately, for .js files in that project, there is no highlighting at all.

Can I enable highlighting in .js files in the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click on the js file you want to edit and select 'Open With > JavaScript Editor' to open the file using the JavaScript editor. You should only have to do this once and your choice of editor will be remembered.